# Zeller's congruence not working correctly using C++

Tags: c++

First time asking here, also new to programming so apologies for anything in advance.

I am having trouble with this exercise that goes like this:

We want you to write a code which finds a weekday number for a date entered by a user.
You'll need three values:

year number (int – let's assume that we're interested only in dates from the 20th and 21st centuries);
month number (int – 1 to 12);
day number (int – 1 to it depends)

1. Decrease month number by 2;
2. if month number becomes less than 0, increment it by 12 and decrement year by 1;
3. take month number and multiply it by 83 and divide it by 32;
4. add day number to month;
5. add year number to month;
6. add year/4 to month;
7. subtract year/100 from month;
8. add year/400 to month;
9. find the remainder of dividing month by 7;
10. Congrats! A weekday number is ready for you! 0 – Sunday, 1 – Monday, ... and so on.

Have i implemented the formula correctly in my code?
Edit: Where is my mistake?

```
// int month, year, day;
//a vector string storing the weekdays : sunday, monday ct

month = month- 2;

    if (month< 0)
    {
        month+= 12;
        year-= 1;
    }

    month= (month* 83) / 32 + day+ year+ (year/ 4) - year/ 100 + year/ 400;

    int r= month % 7;
```

Comment: You said you're having trouble, but didn't mention what the trouble was. You did finish with a yes or no question, but one that could be answered by you already simply by testing the code. Are you asking us whether the code written matches the laundry list of steps (or at least should)?

Comment: Sorry, i meant to ask why wont it output the correct weekday for a given day. Sometimes it gets it right, but mostly not. I cant find my mistake.

Comment: I'd say check your year work. Nowhere in the ZCFs I've seen does the raw year appear; it is always `year %100` to get the year of the century, and `year/100` to get the actual century.

Comment: I did do that now, tested it for today's date and it outputs Monday, obviously wrong.  Im not sure about the congruence either, this version is nowhere in wikipedia or other sources.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Your code works for today's date: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vS4vBv92hdhTFLmz It returns 6. 6 is Saturday. Today is Saturday

Comment: @ThomasSablik youre right, tried your first version!! Im not sure how, since yesterday i had coded it the same way as you. Oh well, thanks for the help everyone!